# Interpretation of "company's turnover"

Tags: meaning

Consider the expression:

> a company's turnover

Would you say that it can be interpreted in 2 ways: 1) the value of the goods and services that a company sells and 2) the rate at which people leave a company and new people arrive?

Or is the phrase not ambiguous at all?

I'm sure we can interpret it as 1) and say "turnover of staff" to avoid ambiguity, but still can "a company's turnover" mean 2)?

Comment: It is generally understood to be 1) the financial transactions, otherwise it would be, for example "the company has a high turnover of staff." It is not ambiguous at all, since the staff turnover is *incidental* to the company's performance.

Comment: Section 2(91) turnover as defined under Indian Companies Act, 2013: "Effective from 12-09-2013. “turnover” means the aggregate value of the realization of amount made from the sale, supply or distribution of goods or on account of services rendered, or both, by the company during a financial year."

Comment: It is impossible to say what any phrase means with any certainty without context. *Turnover* can refer to the rate at which a company sells its products or services; the total revenue of a company; how often its staff members depart and must be replaced; how much of the value of its investments or assets under management it trades in a period; how often it signs new customers or clients; or the pastry it sells made by folding a crust over a filling.

Comment: Funny, I only read it as employee turnover at the company.  I'm guessing my lack of sales experience is showing.  It also shows that it is indeed ambiguous as-is without context.